# What gets lost in a roundtrip between Subversion and Git?

Tags: svn, git

I have been thinking about doing some history rewriting on my Subversion repository, but Subversion is at the moment not very good at that. One option would be to convert to Git (which I gather is considerably better at that sort of thing), do the rewriting, and then convert back to Subversion. What, if anything, is likely to get lost in such a translation (apart from the parts of history that are *supposed* to get lost)?

And just in case anyone feels like offering the suggestion that I just switch to Git for good, the answer is: No, I do not want to do that :-)

The code I used follows below. It depends on having set $REPO_SVN AND $REPO_SVN_CLONE to a set of Subversion repositories, one with the original and one (almost) empty repository to hold the clone. 
(Based on [Google code article on importing from Git](https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ImportingFromGit)):

```
# Create first git repository, containing all my data
git svn clone $REPO_SVN RepoGitA

# Create a svn repository to hold the end product
# It must hold one revision, according to Google Code
# svn propset svn:git:svn 1 WCSvnOut
# svnadmin create RepoSvnOut
# svn co file://`pwd`/RepoSvnOut WCSvnOut
# echo "placeholder" > WCSvnOut/placeholder.txt
# svn add WCSvnOut/placeholder.txt
# svn ci -m "Initial commit of svn-git-svn roundtrip" WCSvnOut

# Create second git repository, connected to the new svn repo
# git svn clone file://`pwd`/RepoSvnOut RepoGitB
git svn clone $REPO_SVN_CLONE RepoGitB

# FROM NOW ON, WORK HAPPENS IN THE SECOND GIT REPOSITORY
cd RepoGitB

# Fetch all the data from the first git repository
git fetch ../RepoGitA

# Create a temporary branch for the fetched repository, and tag its head
git branch tmp $(cut -b-40 .git/FETCH_HEAD)
git tag -a -m "Last fetch" last tmp

# Apply initial commit
# Unfortunately, Git treats the initial commit specially, 
# and in particular, cannot rebase it. Work around this as follows:
INIT_COMMIT=$(git log tmp --pretty=format:%H | tail -1)
git checkout $INIT_COMMIT .
git commit -C $INIT_COMMIT

# Rebase: 
# Apply all the other commits to the temporary branch,
# and make it the new master branch:
git rebase master tmp
git branch -M tmp master

# Here I could do some more work to rewrite the repo history

# Lastly, commit the changes to the fresh svn repo
git svn dcommit
```

Comment: My simple question is: Why do you want to rewrite the history ?

Comment: Mainly for space reasons: I have detailed intermediate history of some large files which are not needed. So I want to clear some of those intermediate commits out.

Answer (score -1):

This does not sound like a good idea. In git, you should only rewrite history which hasn't been published. In subversion and other client-server SCMs, *all* history has been published to the central server, so *no* history is safe to rewrite.

Why do you want to rewrite history? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The changed repository will be replace the old one, and all working copies will be checked out again (not a large project in terms of users). So there is not an issue there. On your second question: I am doing this mainly for space reasons, as I mentioned in another comment.